# What can cause "Unexpected tree in genLoad" in a macro expansion?

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I was trying to produce a small macro to isolate another problem that I was having and started running into this compile-time error.

```
Error:scalac: 
  Unexpected tree in genLoad: test.MacroTest$Baz.type/class scala.reflect.internal.Trees$TypeTree at: source-/Users/jpatterson/test/src/test/scala/test/MacroTest.scala,line-5,offset=114
     while compiling: /Users/jpatterson/test/src/test/scala/test/MacroTest.scala
        during phase: jvm
     library version: version 2.13.0-RC1
    compiler version: version 2.13.0-RC1
  reconstructed args: -deprecation -Vimplicits -language:higherKinds -language:implicitConversions -language:postfixOps -classpath ... (cut)
last tree to typer: Literal(Constant(test.MacroTest.MacroTest$Baz.type))
       tree position: line 4 of /Users/jpatterson/test/src/test/scala/test/MacroTest.scala
            tree tpe: Class(classOf[test.MacroTest$Baz$])
              symbol: null
           call site: constructor MacroTest$$anon$1 in package test
== Source file context for tree position ==
     1 package test
     2 
     3 object MacroTest {
     4   case class Baz(x: Int, y: Int)
     5   implicit def bazRead: Read[Baz] = Read.readFor[Baz]
     6 
     7   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
```

I started working with scala 2.12.8. I tried switching to 2.13.0-RC1 just to see if it was something that was already fixed. It fails the same with both versions of scala.

The macro code:

```
package test

import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context

trait Read[A] {
  def read(in: String): A
}

object Read {
  implicit def intRead = new Read[Int] {
    override def read(in: String): Int = in.toInt
  }

  def CaseClassReadImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Expr[Read[A]] = {
    import c.universe._
    val aType = weakTypeOf[A]

    val params = aType.decls.collect {
      case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m
    }.toList

    val paramList = params.map(param => q"Read.read[${param.typeSignature}](in)")

    val src = q"""
      new Read[$aType] {
        def read(in: String) = ${aType.companion}.apply(..$paramList)
      }
    """

    println(src)
    c.Expr[Read[A]](src)
  }

  def readFor[A]: Read[A] = macro CaseClassReadImpl[A]

  def read[A](in: String)(implicit A: Read[A]): A = A.read(in)
}
```

The code that exercises it:

```
package test

object MacroTest {
  case class Baz(x: Int, y: Int)
  implicit def bazRead: Read[Baz] = Read.readFor[Baz]

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(Read.read[Baz]("4"))
  }
}
```

Compiling the second block causes the error above.

I was expecting this to compile correctly. I put that `println` into the macro definition so that I could just grab the code and try to compile that. When I add that to the second block, it compiles fine. I can even replace `bazRead`'s value with it and everything works as expected: it prints out `Baz(4,4)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your macro, you're trying to splice a type (`aType.companion`) into a position where a term is expected (a `tpe: Type` is transformed into `TypeTree(tpe)`).

Try to replace `${aType.companion}` with `${aType.typeSymbol.companion}`.

---

For deriving type classes it's better to use [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless), [Magnolia](https://github.com/propensive/magnolia) or [Scalaz-deriving](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-deriving) than raw macros.

For example in Shapeless `Read` can be derived as follows

```
import shapeless.{Generic, HList, HNil, ::}

trait Read[A] {
  def read(in: String): A
}

object Read {
  implicit def intRead: Read[Int] = _.toInt

  implicit def hNilRead: Read[HNil] = _ => HNil

  implicit def hConsRead[H, T <: HList](implicit r: Read[H], r1: Read[T]): Read[H :: T] = 
    in => r.read(in) :: r1.read(in)

  implicit def caseClassRead[A, L <: HList](implicit gen: Generic.Aux[A, L], r: Read[L]): Read[A] = 
    in => gen.from(r.read(in))

  def read[A](in: String)(implicit A: Read[A]): A = A.read(in)
}

case class Baz(x: Int, y: Int)

Read.read[Baz]("123") // Baz(123,123)
```

Comment: Yeah, I've never taken the time to get over the shapeless learning curve, but this was just a little example that I through together to try to isolate another problem that I was having. Thanks for the quick reply!